# i.MX6 and Debian

Tags: debian, porting

this is a theoretical question.

I'm quite new in the world of the development boards, and I need to clarify some concepts.

The scope: I need to buy a board based on i.MX6 cpu and I have to install Debian on it.

Those are my questions:

1. Which board should I buy? I looked at [Wonderboard](http://www.wandboard.org) and to the NXP [i.MX6 development board](http://www.mouser.it/new/Freescale-Semiconductor/freescale-imx6-devboards/) but I don't know if they are ok for my scope;
2. Now that I have a board, how can I install Debian? There's a specific way to proceed, or, there's a version of debian that fit that particular development board?

I need to clarify the way to proceed.

Comment: Why do you use Debian instead of building your own Linux with Yocto?

Comment: I don't know, it is a requirement

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to buy the Wandboard quad core. I have one myself and the BSP is pretty update to date.

You could find more information on how to port Debian into the Wandboard [HERE](http://wandboard.org/downloads).  All the instruction are available on that website.

Again, I highly recommend you to explore the Yocto Project and build your own Linux Distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is a requirement so I must use debian. Anyway, I'm very new in the embedded world so I'm quite curious, why should I prefer Yocto?

Comment: you can take look a look at the Wiki [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yocto_Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yocto_Project) Yocto helps you to learn more about embedded system.